# What is use of android:supportsRtl="true" in AndroidManifest xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-applicationinfo

Whenever I created new project in android studio, I got `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my app AndroidManifest File.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</application>
```

What is use in app, or what is advantages & disadvantage when I add or not add in my app AndroidManifest .

Comment: I don't feel this as a duplicate question. Both are regarding RTL, but people who search for these will defer.

Comment: The question to which this is referenced as duplicate is wrong. Totally different context for user searching the question.

Comment: TLDR https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2

Answer (score 96, accepted):

> Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left
>   (RTL) layouts. If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or
>   higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so
>   your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if
>   targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored
>   or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of
>   the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your
>   layouts will always be left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is false.
>
> This attribute was added in API level 17.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

Answer (score 90):

if you are building an app in Arabic, Urdu, Hebrew, etc... or any language that is written from right to left you should set `android:supportsRtl` to `true`, that's how you tell the layout to be from right to left, and The default value of this attribute is false.

Comment: Better than Google documentation.

Comment: Thanks to the other responses, but this kind of response is more usefull and complete the documentation. Thank you @Sarah.

Comment: hi, my app isn't support arabic language but i am using android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest.xml is this problem ?

Comment: @ozanurkan - Not a problem. **This answer is wrong/misleading.** `android:supportsRtl="true"` enables *support* for right-to-left languages. Without this, layout will always be left-to-right, *However* by itself **it does not** change the layout to be from right to left. It simply enables other attributes - one of those new attributes controls whether is left-to-right or right-to-left.

Answer (score 10):

From Android API-Guides:

(developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

> Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts.
>
> If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is false.
>
> This attribute was added in API level 17.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop application which supports `RTL layouts`(layout mirroring) you should tace care of two things

1. Declare supporting RTL mirroring in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true">
</application>
```

2. Use `start/end` instead/in addition to `left/right`

```
android:margineLeft
android:margineStart
```