# Home up button changes its direction when language is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, urdu

I have two languages in my app, English and Urdu. When the language is changed to Urdu home up button changes its direction like this:

[image]

Please help me how can I fix this issue. I want arrow direction to be on left side

Comment: What is your home button? The arrow? It might change direction if Left to Right and Right to Left Layouts have been implemented. Check this by going to developer options and enable RTL Layouts. If that is the case then disable RTL changes.

Comment: yes arrow is home button

Comment: Then simply disable RTL layouts, your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To support right to left screen layout, you have to `android:supportsRtl="true"` line in your `manifest.xml` For example:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
>
```

After writing this tag, the arrow button will appear on the right and other icons on the left.

For more information, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179179/what-is-use-of-androidsupportsrtl-true-in-androidmanifest-xml-file) post.

Comment: I dont want to sift all icon left side , I just want to sift the arrow direction to  left

Comment: Try setting it to false. But I recommend you change your screen layout according to the language being used.

Comment: Its looks very bed .. all setting icons appears on left and app name on right side

Comment: Yes, Its absolutely fine. If you do **Urdu localization**, the app name and other text will displayed from the right. And this will be good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is not issue and supportsRtl.
Because if

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

then view display from right-hand-side.

If false then it'll display as it is.

Can i have your manifest application tag and style which used there?

Comment: i made changes from true  to false now it appears good. It was true before