# Forcing the app to work as LTR

Tags: android

I currently own Galaxy Note 4 with RTL in my language, and whenever I run my app it works from right to left while the app is English.

I need to some kind of "force" the app to be LTR in all kind of devices, RTL and LTR.

How I can force it?

Comment: I think you can use `android:supportsRtl="false"` in your application `manifest` file. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179179/what-is-use-of-androidsupportsrtl-true-in-androidmanifest-xml-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179179/what-is-use-of-androidsupportsrtl-true-in-androidmanifest-xml-file).

Comment: I get application error when I put this. Unable to debug. A package i'm using is supporting RTL so it seem like a problem

Answer (score 34):

Add in styles.xml in your Base App theme style:

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
```

Exemple:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, You save me.

Comment: THANK YOU
I was searching for this problem about a week and NONE of them worked
Your solution worked for me

Comment: It works but nowdays the xml file is `themes.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following attribute on your application manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set android:layoutDirection="ltr" in all xml view