# set the arrangement of activity element to left-to-right (defualt)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

my application has no problem with English input language and elements and widgets are aligned from left to right. but when this application runs on other mobile with other input language (Like Persian) every things aligns from right to left and it isn't my desire.

Is there any comprehensive setting on the application/code that arranges the the entire app element and activities LEFT-TO-RIGHT without considering the mobile input language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817683/forcing-the-app-to-work-as-ltr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can force the app to ignore rtl configurations from the **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file.

Just make `android:supportsRtl` equals **false**.

```
<application
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a layout that is specific to a language, by placing that layout inside an appropriate layout folder. I don't know what the code is for Arabic, but it should be something like `/layout-aa/`

Far better today, however, is to use a relative layout, where you use the `android:gravity="start"` or similar, aligning it based on the language orientation and not strictly left/right. This is available with API version 14 and above.