# Relative dimensions issue with android:supportsRtl="false"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I've used dimensions as paddingStart or paddingEnd instead of paddingLeft or paddingRight, but when i disabled RTL support with 'android:supportsRtl="false"' . Then in whole app the layout is not picking dimens and views are disturbed. I tried a view with replacing paddingStart with paddingLeft and it got corrected. But i don't want to change it in whole app. Is relative dimension scheme supported for RTL support only? what if i want to disable RTL support in a app that previously had that support in it?

Comment: What you want to achieve by disabling RTL support? you want the app to force LTR?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the app to LTR, You can use this answer:

[Force LTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817683/forcing-the-app-to-work-as-ltr/44436035#44436035)

Comment: The above mentioned issue still persists. It seems like relative dimens are not working for support library widgets only by disabling RTL support