# How to change gravity of TextInputEditText in TextInputLayout in Hebrew language?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout

So I am using in my app two languages `English and Hebrew`.

There is how does my TextInputEditText in TextInputLayout looks in English

[image]

All is good in English, but here image of the same View, but in Hebrew

[image]

This password dots I expect them from right side in Hebrew...

If I am setting `android:gravity="end"` , so dots goes to the right side, but hint also goes to the other side (image below)

[image]

I expect in Hebrew hint to be on the right side as well as dots on the right side.

In English hint and dots on left in Hewrew dots and hint on right...

What am I doing wrong?
If I forgot about something fell free to ask

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179179/what-is-use-of-androidsupportsrtl-true-in-androidmanifest-xml-file

Comment: @sarthakGandhi no, it is not good enough... because I don't need flip my layout as mirror